# Remote access an application from another pc

Tags: background-process, remote-access, sharing

I have a application installed in pcA.I want to access this application in pcB from pcA over the network.Remote Desktop Connection in Windows takes away the control from the host so it is not feasible.I want to access the application from pcA in pcB without taking control over pcA's mouse and keyboard.I want to concurrently work on the application from both pcA and pcB.The host should remotely share the application in background so that it doesn't affect the host except the fact that pcA's CPU and memory will be utilized by pcB while using the application.Is this possible?

Comment: Would Chrome Remote Desktop work for you? https://remotedesktop.google.com/ - caveat is that you both need Google accounts signed up and granted for Remote Share on both computers. From there, both of you (PC A accessing PC B) will share the same screen and be able to run the application on PC B.

Comment: PC B takes control of PC A via Chrome remote desktop.It does not run in background.I cannot concurrently work on both the machines at the same time.

Comment: If both PCs are on the same network (i.e. a Shared Drive on PC B is accessible from PC A), then you can run the application through a shared network drive. Note that depending on what the application would be run, it may require some dependencies that will only allow it primarily on the computer where it was installed.

Comment: The application has a one user license,so it detects a intrusion while sharing and limits it functionality when used concurrently.

Comment: Well that answers your question pretty much. Buy additional licenses or restrict the use to the licensed software only.